# R language. How to retrieve random forest residuals?

Tags: r, random-forest

Probably a simple question: how may I to retrieve the residual of regression when using randomForest? (any other package would be accetable)

Thank you and my wishes of a great 2015!

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
library(randomForest)
rf <- randomForest(Fertility ~., swiss) # test run

swiss$Fertility - predict(rf) # residuals
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `rf` is an object of class `randomForest`, you can retrieve `mse` (vector of mean square errors: sum of squared residuals divided by `n`) by doing:

`mse <- rf$mse`